# How write an Excel-VBA code to update an excel sheet with data that is exported from a program?

Tags: vba, excel

Amateur coder here, I'm trying to write an Excel-VBA code that can auto-update rows with newer information that comes from a data dump (The original data comes from a previous dump, just want to keep the excel sheet up to date with the data dump, and keep the user input data aligned with the data dump data). The code should compare the values in the first 4 columns of each row for duplicate data in the whole sheet on the same columns and if it finds a duplicate row with the same data it will replace the original row with the new data [Just an example I fabricated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3fXW.jpg) So in this example, the code would replace row 1:columns EFG with row 8's column EFG since they have all been changed, but keep all the user input data with the newer data. Same goes for row 5 column FG, replaced with row 11, column FG. And so on. Then delete all duplicate rows based on duplicate data in columns A-D. I've written some pretty basic codes in Excel-VBA, but this one is far beyond my capabilities, such that I don't even know where to start. Any advice or a simple starting point would help!

Comment: The way your example is put together you could just paste the new data on top of the old data. If it changes, it changes, if it doesn't, it doesn't. Will there ever be new tasks added? Old tasks taken away?

Comment: I wrote that example as a super clean example. Yes there will be new tasks added and they won't come all organized like that in the same order, but chances are there will not be any old tasks removed.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran some testing on finding duplicates in Excel VBA. It's a commonly asked question on StackOverflow, and answers range from the clunky to the exquisite, using all kinds of methods.

I'm afraid the OP doesn't provide enough information to answer his/her specific question, but obviously he/she will need to write a routine to manage duplicates. So I hope the code below will be of some assistance.

The test involved taking a dataset of 500,000 items, writing the unique values to a new sheet and storing those values in an `array` or `Collection`. I recorded the time to process the tasks using 5 different methods: `Range.AdvancedFilter`, `Collection`, Array Comparison, `Range.RemoveDuplicates` and `Application.Match`. The items were stored in one column only and were strings with 500 unique values (so no dates which can make things more awkward). Results in order of speed were:

1. AdvancedFilter, 0.19 seconds
2. Collection, 1.83 seconds
3. RemoveDuplicates, 2.41 seconds
4. Array Comparison, 37.28 seconds
5. Match, 38.75 seconds

### AdvancedFilter

Pros:

- amazingly fast and surely the best way to remove duplicates.

Cons:

- requires output to a `Range` (so a hidden worksheet may be required)
- includes the header (so some management of the result is required)
- no means of identifying where one item matches another without further coding (so it won't work if you're trying to find a matching value, as this OP will be).

### Collection

Pros:

- All contained within VBA (so works well if you're not writing results to a `worksheet`
- Fairly fast
- Identifies matches (eg value, index of matched item, etc.)
- Enables you to store additional data in the collection associated with the unique value (eg how many times the duplicate occurs, other row values, etc.)

Cons:

- Requires a `String` as a unique key, (so some casting may be needed, and mistakes can occur if the key was originally an `Integer` or `Long` and you forget to convert it to a `String` for your look-up)
- Requires trapping an error to find a duplicate and some developers don't like that as a philosophy ( a `Dictionary` object would circumvent this).

### RemoveDuplicates

Pros:

- Does what it says on the tin - a great technique if you only want to remove duplicates from an existing `Range`
- No need to output results elsewhere
- No problems with headers
- Still respectable speed

Cons:

- As with `AdvancedFilter`, no means of identifying matches without further coding.

### Array Comparison

Pros:

- good for beginners in VBA because the code is easy to understand and write.
- identifies matches and keeps a running count of unique items
- as with Collections, keeps everything within VBA.

Cons:

- Painfully slow (but there's scope for considerable speed improvements if the data is sorted)
- More difficult to write to a `Worksheet` because the resultant array is one-dimensional so managing rows can be a problem. If only VBA let you `ReDim` the first dimension...

### Match

Pros:

- Would work ok if you're only trying to find a single match
- identifies matches

Cons:

- Put the kettle on if you have a large dataset
- inefficient code (but improvements like skipping known duplicates would hugely help)

So, I guess it's difficult to look past `AdvancedFilters` and `Collections` when it comes to managing duplicates, but no one's baby is ugly, so take your pick.

If you're interested the testing code is as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Private mTimer As clsTimer
Private mDataRanges As Collection
Private Const ADV_FILTER_KEY As String = "AdvancedFilter"
Private Const COLLECTION_KEY As String = "Collection"
Private Const ARRAY_COMP_KEY As String = "Array Comparison"
Private Const REMOVE_DUPES_KEY As String = "RemoveDuplicates"
Private Const MATCH_KEY As String = "Match"

Public Sub RunMe()
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet
    Dim outSht As Worksheet
    Dim lastCell As Range
    Dim loc As clsRanges

    'Initialise
    Set mTimer = New clsTimer

    'Idenfity the source data
    Set srcSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SourceData")
    Set outSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("UniqueList")
    Set lastCell = srcSht.Cells(srcSht.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp)

    'Prepare the output sheet
    outSht.Cells.Clear
    outSht.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Type"
    outSht.Cells(2, 1).Value = "Secs"


    'Define the source and output ranges
    Set mDataRanges = New Collection

    Set loc = New clsRanges
    loc.Create lastCell, outSht, 2, True
    mDataRanges.Add loc, ADV_FILTER_KEY

    Set loc = New clsRanges
    loc.Create lastCell, outSht, 3
    mDataRanges.Add loc, COLLECTION_KEY

    Set loc = New clsRanges
    loc.Create lastCell, outSht, 4
    mDataRanges.Add loc, ARRAY_COMP_KEY

    Set loc = New clsRanges
    loc.Create lastCell, outSht, 5
    mDataRanges.Add loc, REMOVE_DUPES_KEY

    Set loc = New clsRanges
    loc.Create lastCell, outSht, 6
    mDataRanges.Add loc, MATCH_KEY

    'Find the unique values using different methods
    UsingAdvFilter
    UsingCollection
    UsingArrayComparison
    UsingRemoveDuplicates
    UsingMatch

End Sub
Private Sub UsingAdvFilter()
    Dim loc As clsRanges
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim rng As Variant
    Dim srcRange As Range
    Dim outRange As Range

    'Start the clock
    mTimer.StartCounter

    'Run the filter to write unique values
    Set loc = mDataRanges(ADV_FILTER_KEY)
    loc.SourceRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=loc.OutputRange, unique:=True

    'Read the unique values into an array
    v = loc.OutputRange.CurrentRegion.Resize(, 1).Value

    'Stop the clock
    loc.OutputRange.Offset(-1).Value = Round(mTimer.TimeElapsed / 1000, 2)

    'Write the heading
    loc.OutputRange.Offset(-2).Value = ADV_FILTER_KEY
    loc.OutputRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
Private Sub UsingCollection()
    Dim col As Collection
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim key As String
    Dim item As Variant
    Dim v() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim loc As clsRanges

    'Start the clock
    mTimer.StartCounter

    'Read the source data into an array
    Set loc = mDataRanges(COLLECTION_KEY)
    data = loc.SourceRange.Value2


    'Prepare error handler to trap duplicate keys
    On Error Resume Next

    'Loop through the data array to find unique values
    Set col = New Collection
    For i = 1 To UBound(data, 1)

        'Define the key (must be a String)
        key = CStr(data(i, 1))

        'Test if collection already contains the key
        'If it doesn't an error 5 will be thrown
        item = col(key)
        If Err.Number = 5 Then 'key doesn't exist
            col.Add data(i, 1), key
            Err.Clear
        ElseIf Err.Number <> 0 Then 'trap any unplanned errors
            MsgBox Err.Description
            End
        End If

    Next

    'Restore the error handler
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Read the unique values into an array
    ReDim v(1 To col.count, 1 To 1)
    i = 1
    For Each item In col
        v(i, 1) = item
        i = i + 1
    Next

    'Write the unique values
    loc.OutputRange.Resize(UBound(v, 1)).Value = v

    'Stop the clock
    loc.OutputRange.Offset(-1).Value = Round(mTimer.TimeElapsed / 1000, 2)

    'Write the heading
    loc.OutputRange.Offset(-2).Value = COLLECTION_KEY
    loc.OutputRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
Private Sub UsingArrayComparison()
    Dim loc As clsRanges
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim tmp() As Variant
    Dim v() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim count As Long
    Dim isUnique As Boolean

    'Start the clock
    mTimer.StartCounter

    'Read the source data into an array
    Set loc = mDataRanges(ARRAY_COMP_KEY)
    data = loc.SourceRange.Value2

    'Dimension the array which will temporarily store unique values
    ReDim tmp(1 To UBound(data, 1))

    'Set the unique counter - use 0 to prevent the loop running on first item.
    count = 0

    'Loop through the data array
    For i = 1 To UBound(data, 1)

        'Test if value is already contained in unique list
        'by iterating through it until a match is found
        isUnique = True
        For c = 1 To count
            If data(i, 1) = tmp(c) Then
                isUnique = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        'If no match is found then add it to the temporary array
        'and increment the count
        If isUnique Then
            count = count + 1
            tmp(count) = data(i, 1)
        End If

    Next

    'Trim the temporary array to the unique count size
    ReDim Preserve tmp(1 To count)

    'Unfortunately we can't write a one-dimensional array to
    'a Worksheet (without using some form of Transposition)
    'so we'll copy it to a two-dimensional one.
    'It would be easier if we could just Dim the tmp array
    'in two dimensions, but ReDim only allows us to adjust the
    'last dimension (ie column), so we can't deal with rows.
    ReDim v(1 To count, 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To count
        v(i, 1) = tmp(i)
    Next

    'Write the unique values
    loc.OutputRange.Resize(count).Value = v

    'Stop the clock
    loc.OutputRange.Offset(-1).Value = Round(mTimer.TimeElapsed / 1000, 2)

    'Write the heading
    loc.OutputRange.Offset(-2).Value = ARRAY_COMP_KEY
    loc.OutputRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
Private Sub UsingRemoveDuplicates()
    Dim loc As clsRanges
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim count As Long

    'Start the clock
    mTimer.StartCounter

    'Resize the output range to match the source data range
    Set loc = mDataRanges(REMOVE_DUPES_KEY)
    Set rng = loc.OutputRange.Resize(loc.SourceRange.Rows.count)

    'Turn off screen updating to keep our test fair
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Write the full source data to the output sheet
    rng.Value = loc.SourceRange.Value2

    'Run the remove duplicates routine
    rng.RemoveDuplicates 1, xlNo

    'Restore screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'Calculate size of range without the duplicates
    count = rng.Cells(rng.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - loc.OutputRange.Row + 1

    'Read the values into an array
    v = loc.OutputRange.Resize(count).Value

    'Stop the clock
    loc.OutputRange.Offset(-1).Value = Round(mTimer.TimeElapsed / 1000, 2)

    'Write the heading
    loc.OutputRange.Offset(-2).Value = REMOVE_DUPES_KEY
    loc.OutputRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
Private Sub UsingMatch()
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim lastPos As Long
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim isUnique As Boolean
    Dim loc As clsRanges
    Dim count As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim tmp() As Variant
    Dim v() As Variant


    'Start the clock
    mTimer.StartCounter

    'Read the source data into an array
    Set loc = mDataRanges(MATCH_KEY)
    data = loc.SourceRange.Value2

    'Dimension the array which will temporarily store unique values
    ReDim tmp(1 To UBound(data, 1))

    'Prepare the loop parameters
    lastPos = UBound(data, 1)
    count = 0

    For i = 1 To lastPos

        If i = lastPos Then 'no need to look for a match as it's the last one
            isUnique = True
        Else
            'Define the search range to be one below the current item to the end.
            Set searchRange = loc.SourceRange.Cells(i + 1, 1).Resize(lastPos - i)
            isUnique = IsError(Application.Match(data(i, 1), searchRange, 0))
        End If

        'If there's no match, add the item to our uniques array
        If isUnique Then
            count = count + 1
            tmp(count) = data(i, 1)
        End If

    Next

    'Trim the temporary array to the unique count size
    ReDim Preserve tmp(1 To count)

    'Same one-dimensional array issue as array method so transpose.
    ReDim v(1 To count, 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To count
        v(i, 1) = tmp(i)
    Next

    'Write the unique values
    loc.OutputRange.Resize(count).Value = v

    'Stop the clock
    loc.OutputRange.Offset(-1).Value = Round(mTimer.TimeElapsed / 1000, 2)

    'Write the heading
    loc.OutputRange.Offset(-2).Value = MATCH_KEY
    loc.OutputRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

... and for completeness, here's the `clsRanges` code:

```
Private mSrcRange As Range
Private mOutRange As Range
Public Sub Create(srcLastCell As Range, outSht As Worksheet, outCol As Long, Optional incHeader As Boolean = False)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long

    Set ws = srcLastCell.Worksheet
    r = IIf(incHeader, 1, 2)
    c = srcLastCell.Column
    Set mSrcRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(r, c), srcLastCell)
    Set mOutRange = outSht.Cells(3, outCol)

End Sub
Public Property Get SourceRange() As Range
    Set SourceRange = mSrcRange
End Property
Public Property Get OutputRange() As Range
    Set OutputRange = mOutRange
End Property
```

Comment: Thanks for your post but it doesn't really address my issue. I can find the duplicates using the excel's built in functions such as highlighting the duplicates with respect to a column or columns, and removing full on duplicates. My real issue is how do I program in the updating of old data with new data once I find the duplicates with updated information?

Comment: It exactly addresses your issue: say you used the `Collection` method, you'd run the routine to find the duplicate, once found you'd read the updated information (say cells B, C, and D) and overwrite the old data, or you could populate the Collection with all the updates and run them all at once at the end. To overwrite the data, it could be as simple as `.Range("B[new]:D[new]").Value = .Range("B[old]:D[old]").Value`